# Storing film in the fridge with air ionizer?

Tags: film, 35mm, kodak

I have several 135 and super8 unexposed film rolls and I'd like to store them in the fridge. However, my fridge has that air ionizer (which should keep food fresh for longer time). Should this ionizer actually damage the film itself?
Thanks.

Comment: I assume they are in air-tight containers, right?  So the ionizer won't matter as there will be no air exchange with them.  Are they?

Comment: @Linwood yes, the 35mm films are in those airtight round plastic cans with lid, super8 cartridges are in plastic foil. So generally as long as they are airtight sealed they should be fine? I had to ask this question because I don't know how strong the ionization in the fridge is, what kind and if film is sensitive to this particular kind.

Comment: I think the answer given is correct in conclusion, though the first paragraph is pretty disconnected from the conclusion, but if the containers are air tight, the ions in the air won't get to the film.  It's highly unlikely if they did it would be an issue. It's more like the slightly charged air you get on a thunder filled nights, a bit more ions in the air, not ionizing radiation (i.e. radiation which can ionize material it strikes) like an x-ray machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Air is a mix of nitrogen and oxygen and other gasses. It is ionized by a device it outputs high voltage. Now film is sensitive to light and ionizing radiation. Could the ionizing device in the refrigerator output X-ray etc.? Possible but unlikely.

Film is a perishable, it has a shelf life.  We can prolong shelf life by refrigeration and by protecting the film from humid conditions. Boxed film has a moisture barrier envelop. The film inside is at near zero as to humidity. Once the packaging is compromised, the shelf life decreases.

I think you can safely store film in refrigerators with an ionizing device.